# Python find element in list that ends with number

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a list of strings, and I want to all the strings that end with `_1234` where `1234` can be any 4-digit number. It's ideal to find all the elements, and what the digits actually are, or at least return the 1st matching element, and what the 4 digit is.

For example, I have

```
['A', 'BB_1024', 'CQ_2', 'x_0510', 'y_98765']
```

I want to get

```
['1024', '0510']
```

Okay so far I got, `_\d{4}$` will match `_1234` and return a match object, and the `match_object.group(0)` is the actual matched string. But is there a better way to look for `_\d{4}$` but only return `\d{4}` without the `_`?

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Have you looked into. `filter`?

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? This question is currently to broad.

Comment: take a look at `split` and `len` and `isdigit` ... or the `re` module

Comment: Too broad? Nonsense, it is very specific. regexs can be very confusing, and capturing groups even more so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

lst = ['A', 'BB_1024', 'CQ_2', 'x_0510']
newlst = []

for item in lst:
    match = re.search(r'_(\d{4})\Z', item)
    if match:
        newlst.append(match.group(1))

print(newlst)  # ['1024', '0510']
```

As for the regex, the pattern matches an underscore and exactly 4 digits at the end of the string, capturing only the digits (note the parens). The captured group is then accessible via `match.group(1)` (remember that `group(0)` is the entire match).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

src = ['A', 'BB_1024', 'CQ_2', 'x_0510', 'y_98765', 'AB2421', 'D3&1345']

res = []
p = re.compile('.*\D(\d{4})$')
for s in src:
    m = p.match(s)
    if m:
        res.append(m.group(1))

print(res)
```

Works fine, \D means not a number, so it will match 'AB2421', 'D3&1345' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please show some code next time you ask a question here, even if it doesn't work at all. It makes it easier for people to help you.

If you're interested in a solution without any regex, here's a way with list comprehensions:

```
>>> data = ['A', 'BB_1024', 'CQ_2', 'x_0510', 'y_98765']
>>> endings = [text.split('_')[-1] for text in data]
>>> endings
['A', '1024', '2', '0510', '98765']
>>> [x for x in endings if x.isdigit() and len(x)==4]
['1024', '0510']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[s[-4:] for s in lst if s[-4:].isdigit() and len(s) > 4]
```

Just check the last four characters if it's a number or not.
added the `len(s) > 4` to correct the mistake Joran pointed out.

Comment: this is simply wrong... consider `s=['123','asd_4421','yello1234','1']`

Answer (score -2):

Try this code:

```
r = re.compile(".*?([0-9]+)$")
newlist = filter(r.match, mylist)
print newlist
```